# Build Controller and Test Agent on separate servers won't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, regression-testing

We have one server with a build controller, one server with a test agent and one server with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimat installed. When we queue a test to build on the controller and run on the agent,
 the test (cuit) builds and runs on the controller. 
The agent is connected to controller and everything seems connected and fine. There has to be one small detail we are missing or some configuraten that is wrong. We have tried to add a new agent on the controller and the "test agent status" on the agent is online and connected to the controller. The drop folder is accessible from all servers with the finished builds inside.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Bjørn

Comment: Can you add more details as to what is the error you are seeing? Is the test failing or not starting at all?

Comment: Our solution was to reinstall the build controller from  scratch - We never found out what the actual problem was, but a reinstall did it.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your solution *.testsettings and set in roles tab remote execution and enter the name of the agent.
In the build definision set the  *.testsettings under run settings.